# Cannot modify Seq.head

Tags: scala

I'm learning Scala, and got confused about Seq.head.

```
scala> x = Array(1, 2, 3)
x: Array[Int] = [I@545e9f15

scala> x
res64: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> x(0)
res65: Int = 1

scala> x.head
res66: Int = 1

scala> x(0) += 1

scala> x.head += 1
<console>:13: error: value += is not a member of Int
       x.head += 1
              ^

scala> x.head = 1
<console>:12: error: value head_= is not a member of scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[Int]
       x.head = 1
         ^

scala>
```

Seems there's some implicit conventions happening beneath.

But from Scala API, the type of Array.head is Int (in my case):

```
def head: T
```

So why can I modify this element?

Comment: Scala philosophy is about immutability. Please have a look at the Scala doc about immutable collection API: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/overview.html

Comment: The question is not very clear. I believe what he wants to know is why can he change the first element by using `x(0)` and not by using `x.head`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key difference in your question is between `x(0) += 1` (which works), and `x.head += 1` (which fails).

`x(0) += 1` is equivalent to `x(0) = x(0) + 1`, which is syntaxic sugar to `x.update(0, x.apply(0) + 1)`. This instruction increases the value of `x(0)`.

`x.head` returns and `Int`, which is immutable, thus `x.head += 1` fails.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this excerpt from the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html) might be useful:

> `val numbers = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)`
>
> `val first = numbers(0)`
>
> `numbers(3) = 100`
>
> Arrays make use of two common pieces of Scala syntactic sugar, shown
>   on lines 2 and 3 of the above example code. Line 2 is translated into
>   a call to apply(Int), while line 3 is translated into a call to
>   update(Int, T).

When you use parenthesis on the left side of assignments they are converted to an update call that replaces the element in the array. The `.head` method does not have such conversion, it is merely a way to get the first element so you can not use it to modify the list.